# How to syncronize BIM360DOCS files with Sharepoint

Tags: api, sharepoint, integration, autodesk-forge

I need to do an automatization process that can transfer files bewtween BIM360DOCS and Sharepoint.

Which Autodesk APIS I must use? How I can do that?

Thanks in advance,

Javier.

Answer (score 0):

Listing, downloading, or uploading of documents in BIM 360 Docs is done through the [Data Management service](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http).

As for some examples, here's how you can download a file using these APIs: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/.

And here's how you can upload a file: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/.

The tutorials use a command line tool (curl) to make all the API requests but you can of course communicate with the APIs from your custom application or script as well, either using the official [Forge SDKs](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge?q=sdk&type=&language=&sort=) available for some of the most popular programming languages, or simply making vanilla HTTP requests in the same fashion.